# JQuery Class Selector on Backbone View

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

My Backbone template has the `.item` class.

The View successfully displays the Model, I can see each `.item` on the web page.

However when I call

```
console.log($(".item"));
```

The resulting array is empty.

Is this normal with Backbone, or is my setup incorrect?  Either way, how do I access the `.items`?

Comment: where do you call console.log($(".item")) ? after render or before ?

Comment: @Evgeniy Oh yeah putting it right after `render()` solved it.  Before the `console.log()` was outside/after all the Backbone code.  If you want to make your comment into an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use correct syntax in `console log`, but be sure you call it in correct way. Before BB view `.render()` output will be empty and after successful `.render()` you will get set of elements. So to make it work move `console.log()` call after render method